# ¿Como puedo enviar un correo para resetear mi contraseña en laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, contraseña

quisiera saber como puedo enviar un correo con los datos para reestablecer la contraseña de un usuario a su direccion de correo (ej. gmail, hotmail, outlook, etc.).
Investigue en algunos lugares y es que usan mailtrap que es un servidor de correos y es ahi donde llegan los correos que yo envio al momento de querer reestablecer una contraseña pero yo quisiera hacerlo con su email original
de antemano agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: Cómo estás enviando los mails para restablecer la contraseña? Cómo es tu tabla de usuarios? Por defecto se envían a la cuenta que figura en el campo email.

Comment: si amigo estoy enviando al correo con el que el usuario se registrar pero en mi caso solo lo envia a la bandeja de mailtrap y no asi al dominio del correo